# anonymous vs. guest logins in vsftpd?

Tags: security, ftp, vsftpd

What's the difference between `anonymous` and `guest` logins in `vsftpd`?

Both can be enabled/disabled:

```
anonymous_enable=
guest_enable=
```

Both are mapped to a different username:

```
ftp_username=
guest_username=
```

Pretty much everything what I know is true for `anonymous` can be applied to `guest`.

Then why `guest` exists if `anonymous` seems good enough?

***EDIT***

Please consider the following `vsftpd` config. On the left hand side I have `anonymous` config, on the right `guest`. Apart those 3 lines the rest of the config is coherent.

```
# Standalone mode               # Standalone mode
listen=YES                      listen=YES

# Access rights                 # Access rights
anon_root=/var/ftp              anon_root=/var/ftp
download_enable=YES             download_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=YES         |  guest_enable=YES
local_enable=NO                 local_enable=NO
ftp_username=ftp             |  guest_username=ftp2

# Upload Access rights          # Upload Access rights
write_enable=YES                write_enable=YES
anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES     anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
anon_other_write_enable=NO      anon_other_write_enable=NO
anon_upload_enable=YES          anon_upload_enable=YES
delete_failed_uploads=YES       delete_failed_uploads=YES

# Security                      # Security
anon_world_readable_only=YES    anon_world_readable_only=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES        connect_from_port_20=YES
hide_ids=YES                    hide_ids=YES
ls_recurse_enable=NO            ls_recurse_enable=NO
tilde_user_enable=NO            tilde_user_enable=NO
pasv_min_port=50000             pasv_min_port=50000
pasv_max_port=60000             pasv_max_port=60000

# Features                      # Features
ftpd_banner=Welcome Anonymou |  ftpd_banner=Welcome Guest !!
no_anon_password=YES            no_anon_password=YES
xferlog_enable=YES              xferlog_enable=YES
```

User experience with `anonymous` enabled:

```
$ lftp -d 127.0.0.1
---- Resolving host address...
---- 1 address found: 127.0.0.1
lftp 127.0.0.1:~> ls
---- Connecting to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 21
<--- 220 Welcome Anonymous !!
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:
<---  EPRT
<---  EPSV
<---  MDTM
<---  PASV
<---  REST STREAM
<---  SIZE
<---  TVFS
<--- 211 End
---> USER anonymous
<--- 230 Login successful. 
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/" is the current directory
---> EPSV
<--- 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||52743|)
---- Connecting data socket to (127.0.0.1) port 52743
---- Data connection established
---> LIST
<--- 150 Here comes the directory listing.
---- Got EOF on data connection
---- Closing data socket
drwxrwxr-x    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Mar 16 13:21 upload
drwxr-xr-x    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Mar 16 13:30 vagrant
<--- 226 Directory send OK.
lftp 127.0.0.1:/> exit
---> QUIT
<--- 221 Goodbye.
---- Closing control socket
```

User experience with `guest` enabled:

```
$ lftp -d 127.0.0.1
---- Resolving host address...
---- 1 address found: 127.0.0.1
lftp 127.0.0.1:~> ls
---- Connecting to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 21
<--- 220 Welcome Guest !!
---> FEAT
<--- 211-Features:
<---  EPRT
<---  EPSV
<---  MDTM
<---  PASV
<---  REST STREAM
<---  SIZE
<---  TVFS
<--- 211 End
---> USER anonymous
<--- 230 Login successful. 
---> PWD
<--- 257 "/" is the current directory
---> EPSV
<--- 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||51032|)
---- Connecting data socket to (127.0.0.1) port 51032
---- Data connection established
---> LIST
<--- 150 Here comes the directory listing.
---- Got EOF on data connection
---- Closing data socket
drwxrwxr-x    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Mar 16 13:21 upload
drwxr-xr-x    2 ftp      ftp          4096 Mar 16 13:30 vagrant
<--- 226 Directory send OK.
lftp 127.0.0.1:/> exit
---> QUIT
<--- 221 Goodbye.
---- Closing control socket
```

As far as I can tell my user experience is not different regardless the configuration.

Comment: Regarding the added "EDIT" section: `anonymous_enable` is enabled by default. You are using it in both cases, that's why there is no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This quote describes it:

> **guest_enable**
>       If enabled, all non-anonymous logins are classed as "guest" logins. A guest login is remapped to the user specified in the
>   guest_username setting.

Anonymous access is intended mainly for providing access to public files to everybody.

Guests need a login/password. Guest feature limits the access only to a group of people (e.g. company employees, or registered customers).